# convert recursion into iteration python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def nested_depth(L):
"""

>>> nested_depth([1, 2, 3])
1
>>> nested_depth([1, [2, 3], 4])
2
"""

    return (1 + max([nested_depth(x) for x in L])
            if isinstance(L, list) else 0)
```

How to convert this recursive code into iterative code? i.e. we have to use loop and we are not allowed to call the function itself.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried converting it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I would use an accumulator. In general, this is a site for help with specific problems, it is not for asking to write code for you...

Comment: This seems like a very homework-ish question. Can you explain what you've tried?

Comment: It's not my homework. Conversion is introduced in class for the first time and I just pick up one of the recursive functions that I wrote before and try to convert it. And I don't know how to start... I just want to know if there is a universal method to solve the convertion like this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a "universal" method for converting recursion to iteration. You must introduce and maintain your own stack to maintain state that was otherwise maintained for you by the stack of function frames executed in recursion. For example:

```
def max_nested_depth(items):
    assert type(items) == list
    max_depth = depth = 1

    # Use a stack to maintain the position in each layer of lists.

    stack = [(0, items)]

    while stack: # Continue until the stack is empty.

        # Iterate each layer until the index exceeds the end of the list.

        while stack[-1][0] < len(stack[-1][1]):

            pos, items = stack[-1]
            stack[-1] = (pos + 1, items)

            if type(items[pos]) == list:

                # Here's the recursion step.

                stack.append((0, items[pos]))
                depth += 1
                max_depth = max(max_depth, depth)

        stack.pop()
        depth -= 1

    return max_depth
```

Comment: You could use `Stack = namedtuple("Stack", "pos items")` and  `top = lambda: stack[-1]` for readability e.g., the loop condition: `while top().pos < len(top().items):`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def maxDepth(L):
...   answer = 1
...   while L:
...     if not any(isinstance(i, list) for i in L):
...       return answer
...     answer += 1
...     L = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i for i in L if isinstance(i, list)]))
... 
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> maxDepth(L)
1
>>> L = [1,[2,3],4]
>>> maxDepth(L)
2
```

Comment: comment will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as @inspectorG4dget

```
def max_depth(L):
    ans = 0
    while L:
        L = [j for i in L for j in (i if isinstance(i, list) else [])]
        ans += 1
    return ans
```